# How to retrieve list of objects by list of fields

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Table *user* has following schema

```
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  ssn integer NOT NULL
```

Spring Data JPA provides following in *CrudRepository* interface to retrieve one user based on id

```
 Optional<User> findById(Integer id);
```

But I want to retrieve all *User.names*,given an list of *id*'s (assume list has no repetions);  how can I retrieve their names. I know I can loop the above *findById*, but that is not practical when table size is very big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findByIdIn` for find by the list of ids and get the user list.

```
List<User> findByIdIn(List<Integer > ids);
```

And for only get names of users of given ids

```
@Query(value = "SELECT c.name FROM User c WHERE id IN (?1)")
public List<String> findAllNames(List<Integer> ids);
```